# How do you say "to stay" or "to visit" a business instead of a person or vacation destination?

Tags: translation, vocabulary

How do you say 'to stay' or 'to visit' a business?

For example: 
"How long do you plan *stay* at the coffee shop?" or
 "We are glad you came *to visit* our store."

Words like 看，访问，住，下榻，... All seem to pertain to traveling, or visiting someone. But my topic is about visiting a business or store instead of a person or vacation destination.

Would 坐 be appropriate? Like 你多久坐在咖啡店？But, I guess that does not work for 'to visit' if it is a grocery store.

Comment: We are glad you came to visit our store.我们很高兴您光临我们的商店。

Comment: How long do you plan stay at the coffee shop? depends on
who says it, if 老板 then also use 光临.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
How do you say 'to stay' or 'to visit' a business?
```

**上** (visit)

> 上酒家 (dine in a restaurant)
>
> 上洒店 (*rent room in a hotel) * *short stay for a night or few hours*
>
> 上酒吧 (visit a bar)

**[光顧](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/12336/)** (patronage; patronize | [粵]: 幫襯 )

> 光顧某店( shop at some store)
>
> 光顧髮型屋 (visit the hair salon)

other usage of 光顧:

> *被小偷光顧 (visited by a thief)*

**逛** (visit/ tour)

> 逛公司 (shop at or window shopping at department store)
>
> 逛遊樂場 (visit / touring amusement park)

**泡** (visit / linger)

> 泡酒吧 ( visit a bar / linger in a  bar)
>
> 泡網吧 (visit or linger in an internet bar)

```
"We are glad you came to visit our store."
```

"我們很高興閣下**光顧/ 光臨**本店" or "歡迎閣下**光臨**本店。"

[閣下](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/48777/): (formal) you

[光臨](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/10173/): (formal) to honor with one's presence; to attend

Answer (score 1):

"上酒吧"and"上酒店"and"上酒家"are all wrong.
The right word is "去"，which generally means "go to".So it should be"去酒吧"or "去酒店".
If you want to use "上" , you should still add "去" after the object. 
Like"上 菜市场 去"（go to the grocery store）or"你 上 哪里 去？"（where are you going?）
Also "逛公司" is wrong. 逛 means shopping or window shopping. 公司 means company. I am not sure what does "visiting a business" mean. If you mean "visting a company and looking around in its building",then you say"参观公司"。“参观” means see an exhibition or a public display in a relatively normal occasion, such as a museum or company or government office etc.

Comment: 'to visit' is a polite way of saying 'come'. 'visit' it usually used for going to someone's home "Come visit us at home." so when it used for a business it is trying to make the customer feel more at home.

Comment: It depends on what you are asking or talking about. There are so many words to express the same meaning in different sentences. Take your example, 'Come visit us at home' can be 欢迎来我家做客 for frends. It can also be '欢迎造访寒舍' in an extremely humble way. 做客 and 造访 all means 'to visit'.As for this sentence: "We are glad you came to visit our store.",you can just say: 欢迎光临 or you can say:'宾至如归'. Actually this two phrases are both very common in China

Answer (score 0):

Full disclosure: my Chinese is more Taiwanese than anything mainland. However, I would say something like "你要在咖啡店留多久？“

Google suggests "你打算在咖啡店呆多久？” which I think is also a good (or probably better) way to say it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my answer will be a little different from China. I am Taiwanese.

Q:How long do you plan stay at the coffee shop?
A1:您打算在咖啡廳待多久呢？（polite way for stranger)
A2:你要在咖啡廳坐多久？（for acquaintance）

Q:We are glad you came to visit our store."
A:我們很高興您來拜訪本店（polite way for stranger)

Answer (score -1):

'to stay' in Chinese is '逗留'  ，'坐'